# Erroneous TeX files with epslatex?

Tags: graphics, pdftex, vim, epslatex, syntax-checker

Upon including the TeX (and eps) file generated from Gnuplot as given in: http://www.gnuplotting.org/output-terminals/#epslatex

I get the following errors with Vim's Syntastic plugin that uses lacheck (tex) & chktex:

```
images/energy.tex|5 error| double space at " \space"
images/energy.tex|5 error| double space at "\space\space"
images/energy.tex|5 error| Do not use @ in LaTeX macro names. "\@spaces"
images/energy.tex|9 error| Use ` to begin quotation, not ' " 'blacktext"
images/energy.tex|21 error| Do not use @ in LaTeX macro names. "\@ifundefined"
images/energy.tex|30 error| Do not use @ in LaTeX macro names. "\g@addto@macro"
images/energy.tex|44 error| Don't use "\expandafter" in LaTeX documents
images/energy.tex|84 error| Don't use "\csname" in LaTeX documents
```

Is this a problem with Gnuplot's epslatex terminal, or Vim's Syntastic, or something I might've done?

p.s. Upon compiling with pdflatex, it does so and gives me an appropriate pdf with the figure and text in it present in the right places. So there is no problem there. Just want to know what these errors are because it is annoying to find the real errors amidst these, in Vim's error display.

Comment: macro names with `@` are not normally allowed in documents but are allowed in package and other internal code, or in the scope of `\makeatletter` your syntax checker is presumably checking for document conventions and shouldn't be used on such code.

Comment: I see... So do you think the other errors are such issues too? If so, any idea how I can make it not look inside something I've added using `\input{filename}` ?

Comment: it's all fine, the whole point of `.. \space\space` for example is to get a double space into an "ascii-art" alignment in a warning message text so being told that it is a double space is true but not very useful.

Comment: my usual approach to problems with vim would be to use emacs (but I'll delete this comment in a bit:-)

Comment: I know nothing about vim but probably you could use `\mysecretcommand{filename}`  with `\newcommand\mysecretcommand{\input}` then latex will input the file but the syntax checker probably won't trace the definition so won't know it is an input.

Comment: It works! But it now gives me an error: `Could not execute LaTeX command.`, referring to the `\newcommand{\putin}{\input}` line that I added, but I hope it is a harmless error. I'm suppressing it with a `% chktex 27`
Oh, and could you post an answer so I can accept ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  then I guess you do not use emacs much, due to how few problems vim causes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors from the syntax checker are all spurious complaining about internal code constructs that probably should not be at the top of level of a document, but are fine (and in some cases necessary) in internal package (and generated) code.

You can probably stop the syntax checker following the `\input` and checking the file by using a custom input command (it probably already does not follow files loaded by `\usepackage` for example)

for example after

```
 \newcommand\mysecretcommand{\input}
```

You could do

```
 \mysecretcommand{filename}
```

and it will not check the nested file (but might moan about `\mysecretcommand` that it does not understand)

Comment: shouldn't `\mysecretcommand` sit inside curly brackets ?

Comment: @physkets makes no difference:-)